# MySQL COUNT return 0 if it's not null

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I need to count all articles between dates. I used `IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)` which returns null.

```
SELECT posts_count, dates.fulldate
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(post_id), 0) AS posts_count, DATE_FORMAT(post_created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") AS pdate
   FROM posts
   WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND NOW()
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(post_created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")) t
ON t.pdate = dates.fulldate
WHERE dates.fulldate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND CURDATE() ORDER BY dates.fulldate ASC;
```

> The result is:

```
NULL |  2020-05-20    
NULL |  2020-05-21    
NULL |  2020-05-22    
7634 |  2020-05-23    
51224 | 2020-05-24
```

> The result I want its:

```
   0 |  2020-06-16   
1233 |  2020-06-15    
4354 |  2020-06-14   
   0 |  2020-06-13    
   0 |  2020-06-12
```

Comment: Could you add the Data source of your result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems more complicated than it needs to be. I don't see the point for the subquery that groups post by date and for filtering twice on the dates.

I think the logic you want is:

```
select count(p.post_id) post_count, d.fulldate
from dates d
left join posts p
    on  p.post_created_at >= d.fulldate
    and p.post_created_at <  d.fulldate + interval 1 day
where d.fulldate >= current_date - interval 1 month
group by d.fulldate
order by d.fulldate
```

I would expect that this should be much more efficient than you original code, especially because not date function is applied on the post date column. I would recommend an index on `posts(post_created_at)` to take full advantage of this code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the `IFNULL()` in the main query, not the subquery. The subquery isn't returning any rows for the missing dates, so there isn't even a null count to convert to 0.

```
SELECT IFNULL(posts_count, 0) AS posts_count, dates.fulldate
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS posts_count, DATE_FORMAT(post_created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") AS pdate
   FROM posts
   WHERE DATE_FORMAT(post_created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND NOW()
   GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(post_created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")) t
ON t.pdate = dates.fulldate
WHERE dates.fulldate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND CURDATE() 
ORDER BY dates.fulldate ASC;
```